# ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql

To tentando colocar id como chave primária mas dá esse erro:

> ALTER TABLE causes auto_increment resequencing, resulting in duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: O campo já não é PK !?

Comment: Não, se fosse ia dar esse erro Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.? por que estou tentando editar as tables mais ta dificil

Comment: Certifique-se que nenhum **valor** da coluna **ID** esteja duplicado!

Comment: Qual o comando que apresentou erro?

Answer (score 10):

Tem alguma linha com valor 0 ou NULL nesse campo? Se sim, vai precisar de dar um update neles antes para algum valor maior do que zero. Pode voltar para 0 depois se quiser.

Comment: Não, tava A_I selecionado tirei e deu isso Duplicate entry '1' for key primary

Comment: Não tem valor que não é positivo nessa coluna e todos os valores positivos são distintos entre si?

Comment: Faz um `SELECT id, count(*) FROM table_name GROUP BY id` e procura pelo Id que tem `count()` maior que 1.